# Error when connecting to redshift: "server certificate does not match host name"

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift

After trying to run a query on redshift, I get the following error message:

> OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) server certificate for
>   "" does not match host name "".

I already installed the sqlalchemy-redshift package, as well as the Psycopg2 package. My code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

def run_query(query, connection_string):

 red_engine = create_engine(connection_string)
 data_set = pd.read_sql_query(query, red_engine)

 return data_set
```

The exact same code does work on another computer, so we are sure that the login name, password and queries are correct, and the problem is specific to my computer. Any suggestions?

Comment: The error is pretty clear on what you should check and fix (the certificate).

Comment: Thanks! Can you also tell me how I do that? @IljaEverilä

Comment: This might be helpful: https://github.com/sqlalchemy-redshift/sqlalchemy-redshift/issues/106. What is actually wrong depends on how you're trying to connect to your server, what the certificate contains etc.

Comment: Solution: add sslmode prefer to the function:

`create_engine(connection_string, connect_args={'sslmode': 'prefer'})`

Comment: ["prefer (default) first try an SSL connection; if that fails, try a non-SSL connection"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PQCONNINFO), so no SSL then.

Comment: Hey, I also ran into this issue recently. Did anyone figure out how to get around this without switching the sslmode to prefer? Per this documentation:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq-ssl.html it is not recommended to use sslmode=prefer in production because it permits the possibility of unencrypted connections. I filed a support ticket with AWS to resolve this issue and have not yet received any info from them. Like Ilja Everilä suggested, I thought it may be an issue with the connection method, but I have been able to connect to other databases in the same manner/network

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me in the end: we added a preferred sslmode to our code, as follows:

```
create_engine(connection_string, connect_args={'sslmode': 'prefer'})
```

Comment: I would recommend using `create_engine(connection_string, connect_args={'sslmode': 'verify-ca'})` instead. Per the docs at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq-ssl.html `sslmode=prefer` is just for backwards compatibility. From my understanding:

1. You will attempt to establish an ssl enabled connection
2. You will fail to establish said connection (because of the error you are experiencing)
3. You will revert to an unencrypted connection instead

`verify-ca` will skip the hostname verification portion (so it should still work) but will still encrypt the connection

Comment: I also think using `prefer` is a bad idea.